# VS 2013, visual web part - "Design View" on *.ascx files does not work

Tags: error, visual-studio-2013

I have VS 2013 with last updates and service-pack.

VS hangs, the window does not show design mode(remains in "view source"), then need to close/reopen tab with `.ascx` file. It is on all visual webparts, newly created too

I suspect that there is some application conflict.

Comment: _Design view_ is not usable in VS, IMO. The only time I use it is when I need a single button in a proof of concept scenario.

Comment: I have foreign visual web part that I need to change and rebrand. So in my case it was necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case solution is - uninstall and reinstall VS(I suspect possibly the error was caused by CKS Addition).